# OpenSUSE graphical login lost after distribution upgrade from 11.2 to 11.3

Tags: opensuse, login

I attempted to perform an in-place distribution upgrade from openSUSE 11.2 to openSUSE 11.3 following [the instructions](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aSystem_upgrade). The upgrade appeared to succeed, but after I rebooted I was presented with a console login. It seems that I lost the graphical login.

How do I restore the graphical login?

Comment: What desktop manager had you used? Does a newer version of it exist in 11.3?

Comment: How do I tell which desktop manager I had? It was the one with a bar at the bottom with a button and menu.

Comment: That description fits vast majority of them :) A proprietary driver for graphic card might be another reason for the problem.

Comment: I think you may be right about the graphics driver. I can get to the login screen and desktop in failsafe mode, although then I can't use my mouse... I am running openSUSE in vmWare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am running openSUSE in VMWare, there was a problem with the proprietary drivers. I reinstalled VMWare Tools and everything's working now.